# Построчное считывание из файла

Tags: c#

Не могу закинуть в массив string данные из файла.

```
public partial class Settings : Form
{
    public static string Server { get; set; }
    public static string DataBase { get; set; }
    public static string Login { get; set; }
    public static string Password { get; set; }
    public static MySqlSslMode SslMode { get; set; }
    public static int Port { get; set; }
    string[] str=new string[6];
    public Settings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Settings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MySqlSslMode));
        string[] str = new string[6];
        FillArrStringAsync();
        label7.Text = str[0];
        label8.Text = str[1];
        label12.Text = str[2];
        label11.Text = str[3];
        label10.Text = str[4];
        label9.Text = str[5];
    }
    public string FillArrString()
    {
        string[] str = new string[6];
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"SettingsProgram.txt", Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            int tempVar = 0;
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                str[tempVar] = reader.ReadLine();
                tempVar++;
            }    
        }
        return String.Concat(str);
    }
    public async void FillArrStringAsync()
    {
       await Task.Factory.StartNew(FillArrString);

    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "" && textBox5.Text != "" && maskedTextBox1.Text != "" && comboBox1.Text != "")
        {
            Server = textBox1.Text;
            DataBase = textBox5.Text;
            Login = textBox2.Text;
            Password = textBox3.Text;
            SslMode = (MySqlSslMode)Enum.Parse(typeof(MySqlSslMode), comboBox1.Text);
            Port = Convert.ToInt32(maskedTextBox1.Text);
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"SettingsProgram.txt", false, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                writer.Write(Server + "\r\n");
                writer.Write(DataBase + "\r\n");
                writer.Write(Login + "\r\n");
                writer.Write(Password + "\r\n");
                writer.Write(SslMode.ToString() + "\r\n");
                writer.Write(Port.ToString() + "\r\n");
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Заполните все поля!", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

При отладке мы через FillArrStringAsync получаем из файла данные, все работает. Но когда я пытаюсь при загрузке формы заполнить этими значениями лэйблы то не заполняется, просто пустая строка. Кто знает почему такое может быть? Еще заметил что при работе функции FillArrString через debug у меня все значения проскакивают но на выходе я получаю все равно пустой массив.

Comment: А что за магия у вас с множественной инициализацией массива?

Comment: очевидно, вы в лейблы пытаетесь записать данные из локальной переменной `str`, которую не заполняете. А заполняете вы совсем другую локальную переменную в другом методе, но просто с тем же именем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чуть чуть переписал ваш код

```
private async void Settings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MySqlSslMode));
    string[] str = await FillArrStringAsync();  
    label7.Text = str[0];
    label8.Text = str[1];
    label12.Text = str[2];
    label11.Text = str[3];
    label10.Text = str[4];
    label9.Text = str[5];
}

public Task<string[]> FillArrStringAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(()=>File.ReadAllLines(@"SettingsProgram.txt", Encoding.UTF8));
}
```

---

**UPD**

Проблема была в том, что вы заполняли одну переменную, а читали из другой

```
private void Settings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MySqlSslMode));
    string[] str = new string[6];  //<<<<< это одна переменная
    .......
}
public string FillArrString()
{
    string[] str = new string[6]; // <<<< а это совсем другая переменная
    ........
}
```

Как исправить? Самый простой способ - у вам есть функция, которая читает данные из файла. Пусть она эти данные и возвращает. То есть:

```
private async void Settings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MySqlSslMode));
    string[] str =await  FillArrStringAsync();

    label7.Text = str[0];
    label8.Text = str[1];
    label12.Text = str[2];
    label11.Text = str[3];
    label10.Text = str[4];
    label9.Text = str[5];
}
public string[] FillArrString()
{
    string[] str = new string[6];
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"SettingsProgram.txt", Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        int tempVar = 0;
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            str[tempVar] = reader.ReadLine();
            tempVar++;
        }
    }
    return str; // считанное значение возвращаем из функции. 
                // Любой, кто функцию вызовет, получит в ответ считанное значение. 
}
public Task<string[]> FillArrStringAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(()=>FillArrString());
}
```

Comment: Все заработало. Но подскажите в чем была собственно проблема? Я был поправил код, и оставил только глобальный массив str и с ним работал, а потом с него пытался заполнить.

Comment: @GnomSkull обновил ответ

Comment: @GnomSkull глобальное поле бы вам не подошло, вы же запускаете считывание параллельно, то есть даже если бы вы просто переменную сделали глобальной, то в момент заполнения лейблов не факт, что файл был бы уже считан. То есть вам надо 1) Дождаться, когда считается файл 2) Потом уже заполнять лейблы. В моем коде я жду при помощи оператора await